# Flutter TextEditingController Listener called too many times

Tags: android, ios, dart, textfield, flutter

Ok, so I have one screen with a textfield, which has a textEditingController, with a listener that is added once in the init state. The listener function pushes a new screen, and then when I pop this screen, the listener function is called immediately again, unless I remove the listener immediately after pushing the Screen. I either need to figure out how to prevent the listener function from being called, or distinguish which calls to the listener function are not solely from the user clicking on the textfield. I'm guessing the second option is what is right, but I'm fairly new to flutter so I'm clueless as to how to do this. Thanks u guys!!

Heres's a basic overview of my code....

SCREEN 1

```
class SubmitPost extends StatefulWidget{

  _submitPostState createState() => new _submitPostState();

}



class _submitPostState extends State<SubmitPost>{

final originTextContoller = new TextEditingController();

 void initState() {
    super.initState();

originTextContoller.addListener(_onOriginTouch);



   }


_onOriginTouch() {


    // my guess is that I need some type of conditional statement to determine wheter or not this function was triggered by the user or the "notifyAllListeners" function which is getting called for some reason. I think that's what's happening but idk...



    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PlacePicker()));


}



  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the Widget is removed from the Widget tree

     originTextContoller.removeListener(_onOriginTouch);
    originTextContoller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }


}
```

SCREEN 2

```
class PlacePicker extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
  _PickerState createState() => new _PickerState();
}

class _PickerState extends State<PlacePicker> {

 // basically just a list view with on tap meathod below



    onTap: () async {  // async needed for separate function not called now

      Navigator.pop(context);

}



}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Opening a new screen on TextEditingController events seems weird.

Comment: Well, I'd like to understand why this is happening, as I was able to implement this in swift. Text get's sent back to screen 1 after popping, so I can update the text on the textfield.....Alternatively, I could use a button and just add text to the button, but I feel like there is something that could be learned here that could be beneficial in the future so I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the TextField's eventListener is triggered is because it gets focused upon popping the second screen to go back to the first screen. You may want to consider placing the `Navigator` on a Button instead of a Listenber.